# Como puedo crear una opcion que al digitar una opción lo deje avanzar en el programa o lo devuelva?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

hola buenas soy nueva en c++ y queria pedirles ayuda para ver si me ayudaran a crear una opcion que diga desea volver a calcular otra cosa, y si le le dan **S** lo devuelva y si le da **N** lo deje seguir, normal.

se que esto se hace con un (do while) pero nose como hacer para que valide correctamente S como si y N como no

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numero1, numero2;
    do{

    cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :";
    cin>>numero1;

    cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :";
    cin>>numero2;


    int resultado = numero1 + numero2;

    cout<<"El resultado es :"<<resultado;
    int opcion;
    cout<<"QUIERE calcular otra suma (S/N)";
    cin>>opcion;
    }while(opcion = 'N')


return 0;
}
```

me imaginaba un do while asi pero no estoy segura que tengo mal, otro detalle es que esto lo debo pasar a una funcion entonces debe ser con un do while

Comment: Para recibir ayuda edita tu pregunta y pon el código que llevas

Comment: ok voy  hacerlo gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los errores de tu código ya fueron mencionados [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/465226/193364), ahora ya que estas iniciando en el mundo de la programación te dejo 2 Tips espero te sirvan.

1. No declares variables que no sean necesarios, esto lo digo porque la variable `resultado` no es necesario debido a que no va ser usado en ninguna operación como si haces uso de `numero1` y `numero2` para guardar el valor ingresado por teclado y posteriormente sumarlos, la variable `opcion` lo usas para verificar si se va realizar una nueva suma.
2. Si bien es cierto pides que ingresen las letras `S` o `N` ya sean `minúscula` o `mayúscula`, pero que va pasar si ingresa una letra diferente, quizás para tu ejercicio no sea relevante este dato pero cuando realices programas para ser usado por una tercera persona es importante validar cada ingreso que realice el usuario y no está demás que te vayas acostumbrando.

Te dejo el código con las sugerencias escritas.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numero1, numero2;
    char opcion;

    do{    
        cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :";
        cin>>numero1;
        cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :";
        cin>>numero2;
               
        cout<<"El resultado es :"<<numero1 + numero2<<endl;
        
        cout<<"QUIERE calcular otra suma (S/N)"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;
        
        //Si ingresan por teclado una letra diferente a S,s,N,n  
        while(opcion!='S'&&opcion!='s'&&opcion!='N'&&opcion!='n'){                 
                cout<<"Ingrese solo las teclas S o N en mayuscula o minuscula!!!"<<endl;                
                cin>>opcion;        
        }

    }while((opcion == 'S') || (opcion == 's')); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por los datos

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas sobre tu código:

1. Te recomiendo declarar todas tus variables al principio, no en las líneas que lo necesites, ya que tendrás así el código más ordenado.
2. Al final de la instrucción `while` te faltaba cerrar con un `;`
3. En el `while` estabas asignando (`=`) en vez de comparando (`==`)
4. La variable `opcion` la vas a comparar con los caracteres `S` o `N`, por lo que debería ser de tipo `char`.
5. No tiene sentido que compares con la opción `N`, ya que lo que quieres es que si la opción es igual a SI, entonces repita el bucle.

El código que buscas quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numero1, numero2, resultado;
    char opcion;

    do{
    
        cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :";
        cin>>numero1;
        cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :";
        cin>>numero2;

        resultado = numero1 + numero2;
        cout<<"El resultado es :"<<resultado<<endl;

        cout<<"QUIERE calcular otra suma (S/N)"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;

    }while((opcion == 'S') || (opcion == 's'));


    return 0;
}
```

¡OJO! He tenido que añadir en el `while` la comparación con `S` y `s`, ya que son caracteres diferentes y por lo tanto su valor ASCII es diferente. De este modo da igual si lo que introduces es mayúscula o minúscula.

Un saludo.

Comment: "_Te recomiendo declarar todas tus variables al principio, ... , ya que tendrás así el código más ordenado_". Al final es una cuestión de estilo, pero yo recomendaría no hacer eso. Primero, en funciones mas largas no deja claro cual es el scope de las variables (`numeroX`, y `resultado`, los usaras solo en el `do`? O se usan mas adelante?).

Comment: Y segundo, no te dejara declarar algunas variables que tienen que ser constantes. `resultado` se modificara despues de calcularse? Si ese no es el caso, deberia ser `const int resultado = numero1 + numero2;`. De ese modo tu código es mas descriptivo, y te ahorraras errores.

Comment: ok gracias por los consejos